# Pushviewcontroller and Tab Switch at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a three tab controller bar.  Each is going to utlize a webview.  I am trying to push a link in a url from tab 1's webview in to tab 2's webview.  I have spent probably 12 hours on this and am still running into the same issues.  I finally determined I needed something like so:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers     objectAtIndex:1];
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ClientViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ClientView"];
[vc setTempUrl:self.urlstring];
[navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

What am I missing here?  In the output, I keep getting "unrecognized selector to instance."

ClientViewController.m (I assume this is all you need?)

```
NSString *str = tempUrl;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

ClientViewController.h

```
@interface ClientViewController : UIViewController{
    NSString *myUrl;
    NSString *tempUrl;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *myUrl;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *tempUrl;
```

All Output Log:

> [ClientViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20874980
>   2013-04-11 12:31:35.599 Access Portal[2785:907] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  -[ClientViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20874980

Comment: Please post the code on the receiving side and the contents of your header files.

Comment: yes please, that'd be helpful

Comment: Hopefully that's all you need?

Comment: Mm.. Have a look at this. It can help you: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-5-How-To-Share-Data-Between-View-Controllers-using-a-Singleton

Comment: "In the output, I keep getting "unrecognized selector to instance." Please give the entire error message! And say which line is causing it. We need to know *what* selector and *what* instance (and what line).

Comment: @Jordan - I guess that's where I'm headed if no one has answer here.  I am pretty frustrated with it, and probably should have come here a lot sooner.

Comment: Your view controller at index 1 of that tab bar controller's viewControllers appears to be a ClientViewController, not a navigation controller, which is why you get that error. Put in a log for navigationController, and see what it gives you.

Comment: How do I got about doing that rdelmar?

Comment: After the first line you have posted above, put NSLog(@"%@",navigationController);